# Will WCF publish these properties in the service Metadata?

Tags: .net, wcf

Will WCF expose these properties in the service metadata? Because `[DataContract]` attribute is not assigned to the class.

```
public class Contact
{
  [DataMember]
  public string FirstName {get;set;}

  [DataMember]
  public string LastName;
}
```

Comment: In your case what it is doing? Please give it a try and post how is it behaving in your case.

Answer (score 1):

From *Programming WCF Services, Third Edition* by Juval Löwy
Copyright © 2010 Juval Löwy.

> If the type already contains DataMember attributes (but not a
>   DataContract attribute), these data member contracts will be ignored
>   as if they were not present.

If all attributes are left off then WCF will infer and apply the [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes in the metadata.